# How to load ESB Volume by ID via .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to mount the same volume for a Beanstalk build but can't figure out how to make it work with the volume-id.

I can attach a new volume, and I can attach one based on a snapshot ID but neither are what I'm after.

My current .ebextension

```
commands:
  01umount:
    command: "umount /dev/sdh"
    ignoreErrors: true
  02mkfs:
    command: "mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdh"
  03mkdir:
    command: "mkdir -p /media/volume1"
    ignoreErrors: true
  04mount:
    command: "mount /dev/sdh /media/volume1"

  option_settings:
   - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
     option_name: BlockDeviceMappings
     value: /dev/sdh=:20
```

Which of course will mount a new volume, not attach an existing one. Perhaps snapshot is what I want and I just don't understand the terminology here?

I need the same data that was on the volume when the autoscaling kicks in to be on each EC2 instants that scales... A snapshot would surely just be the data that existed at the point the snapshot was created?

Any ideas or better approaches?

Comment: You can only attach a volume to a single instance, so when your second instance launches, attaching a volume by id would be a fairly meaningless concept.

Comment: Hmm was unaware of this... Any ideas on alternative methods for persistent storage?

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Block Store (EBS) allows you to create, snapshot/clone, and destroy virtual hard drives for EC2 instances.  These drives ("volumes") can be attached to and detached from EC2 instances, but they are not a "share" or shared volume... so attaching a volume by ID becomes a non-useful idea after the first instance launched.

EBS volumes are hard drives.  The analogy is imprecise (because they're on a SAN) but much the same way as you can't physically install the same hard drive in multiple servers, you can't attach an EBS volume to multiple instances (SAN != NAS).

Designing with a cloud mindset, all of your fixed resources would actually be on the *snapshot* (disk image) you deploy when you release a new version and then  use to spawn each fresh auto-scaled instance... and nothing persistent would be stored there because -- just as important as scaling up, is scaling down.  Autoscaled instances go away when not needed.

AWS has [Simple Storage Service (S3)](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) which is commonly used for storing things like documents, avatars, images, videos, and other resources that need to be accessible in a distributed environment.  It is not a filesystem, and can't properly be compared to a filesystem, because it's an object store... but is a highly scalable and highly available storage service that is well-suited to distributed applications.  s3fs allows an S3 "bucket" to be mounted into your machine's filesystem, but this is no panacea.  That mechanism should be reserved for back-end process use, if you use it at all, because it's not appropriate for resources like code or templates, and will not perform as well for serving up content as S3 will perform if used as designed, with clients directly accessing it over https.  You can secure the content through more than one mechanism, as documented.

AWS also now has [Elastic File System (EFS)](http://aws.amazon.com/efs/) which sets up an array of storage that you *can* mount from all of your machines, using NFS.  AWS provides the NFS server and the back-end storage.  Unlike EBS, you do not need to know how much storage to provision up front, because it scales up and down based on what you've stored, billing you  This service is still in "preview" as of this writing, so should not be used for production data.

Or, you can manually configure your own NFS server and mount it from the autoscaling machines.  Making such as setup fail-safe is a bit tricky, though.